# How to do a "Clean Boot" with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Ideally, I'd like to write the *current* status of any apps/svcs that will be changed, so the system could be restored programmatically as well. This is why I chose a CSV file to hold that data.

Here is how far I am in documenting which of each needs to be disabled (and later re-enabled at next boot):

(PowerShell 5 for now)

```
$svcsRunning = @()
$svcResults = @()
$svcsRunning = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "State = 'Running'"

ForEach ($s in $svcsRunning) {
    $svcDetails = @{
        Date = get-date              
        ExitCode  = $s.ExitCode                 
        Name      = $s.Name
        ProcessId = $s.ProcessId
        StartMode = $s.StartMode
        State     = $s.State
        Status    = $s.Status
    }
    # for iterations
    $svcResults += New-Object PSObject -Property $svcDetails  
}
# when done, export
$svcResults | export-csv -Path c:\users\yumi\startupServices.csv -NoTypeInformation

$appsRunning = @()
$appResults = @()
$appsRunning = Get-WmiObject Win32_StartupCommand
ForEach ($a in $appsRunning) {
    $appDetails = @{
        Date = get-date              
        Caption          = $a.Caption                 
        ClassPath        = $a.ClassPath
        Command          = $a.Command
        Container        = $a.Container
        Description      = $a.Description
        Location         = $a.Location
        Name             = $a.Name
        Path             = $a.Path
        Site             = $a.Site
        User             = $a.User
        UserSID          = $a.UserSID
    }
    # for iterations
    $appResults += New-Object PSObject -Property $appDetails  
}
# when done, export
$appResults | export-csv -Path c:\users\yumi\startupApplications.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm not sure if the above can show *all* apps/svcs that need to be disabled for a clean boot.

Comment: this does not cover your main question, but it shows one way to build a system with the previous config ... Reverse Desired State Configuration: How it works – Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog — https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2017/10/27/reverse-desired-state-configuration-how-it-works/